# Creating new classes/members at run-time in scripting languages used in C++

Tags: c++, lua, swig, squirrel

I've been working on this problem off and on for a few months, and now wanted to really come up with a proper solution that will handle the case of creating new user-defined classes (and instances of those classes) with member functions/properties at run-time in a C++11 project.

So far, I've been using SWIG (formerly with Python, now with Lua, exploring Squirrel).  Like all the C++ binding/embedding libraries I've encountered so far (Luna*, luabinder, luabind, OOLua, Sqrat/Sqext, Squall), all expect your classes to be predefined in C++ prior to code execution because they either rely on preprocessor directives or templates.

So my question is, are there any libraries out there that use a more procedural approach to wrapping a language, or are there any good tutorials/examples for something like Lua or Squirrel, that one would recommend for handling the creation of custom-named classes with custom members and functions?  Some direction would be greatly appreciated.

Even simply a good example showing how to create a custom class with a function and a property, in either Lua, Squirrel, via their respective C++ APIs without the use of macros/templates/dynamically-generated code, would be hugely helpful.

EDIT: I have gone as far as creating an `Instance` class that contains a `std::vector` of members key/value pairs, and a member identifying the type so functions can be looked up.  However, there is very little documentation out there on creating simple classes in Lua/Squirrel without the use of static code.

EDIT 2: I would like a solution that works on any platform and without having to dynamically link.

Comment: It is possible to create a C++ class (say `CXX_class`) that wraps a Python object of a certain Python class (say `Py_class`). It is then possible to extend `Py_class` and make instances of `CXX_class` wrap instances of child classes instead. This is how we normally add new classes to a C++ program at run time. If you need something else, please describe your desired C++ interface. What functions/objects should the C++ side see and what should be the result of using them.

Comment: @n.m. I think you're right that I'm looking at this problem the wrong way - over-complicating things when you're right, I can just have some sort of proxy class that represents my user-defined ones. Point taken :P.

Comment: You can't add C++ classes at runtime full stop. You can add Python/Lua/etc classes at runtime however.

Comment: @n.m. I have updated my question to be a bit more specific. I think it may help you to provide me a more clear answer.

Comment: @Mike Weir do you want to be able to create classes dynamically using a scripting languague like Lua, that you will be able to access and use in C++ using some sort of API or did I understand it the wrong way ;) ?

Comment: @AdrianLis That's pretty much it, yep :). I'm currently attempting to use the following as a reference for learning, but it only covers functions and not properties (where I have getter and setter functions) - http://cfc.kizzx2.com/index.php/binding-c-classes-to-lua-a-step-by-step-example-for-beginners/

Answer (score 2):

Creating a class derived from some existing C++ class is the only way (known to me) to bring a new class into a running C++ program. Short of dynamically compiling actual C++ source and loading the resulting library, there is no way to physically add a new class. The next best thing is to create a proxy object in C++ that wraps a Python (Lua etc) object, and make that Python (Lua) object an instance of a class that extends an existing C++ class mirrored to the Python (Lua) side.

```
        C++

     +---------+         mirrors                   +--------------+
     | class X |  ...............................> | class X      |
     +---------+                                   | mirrored to  |
          |                                        | Python       |
          | inherits                               +--------------+
          v                                      inherits  |
     +-----------------+                                   v
     | class X_Wrapper |        references         +--------------+
     |    | python obj ------------------------->  | class CX(X): |
     +-----------------+                           |    def met() |
                                                   +--------------+
```

Here's an example of extending a C++ class with Python, using boost::python as a bridge.

C++ side:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::python;
// this is the interface we will implement in Python
struct World
{
    virtual std::string greet() = 0;
    virtual ~World() {}
};

// this is a helper class needed to access Python-overrided methods
struct WorldWrap : World, wrapper<World>
{
    std::string greet()
    {
        return this->get_override("greet")();
    }
};

// This function tests our class implemented in Python
std::string test(World* w)
{
    std::cout << "Calling w->greet() on some World-derived object\n";
    return w->greet();
}

// This is what the Python side will see
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<WorldWrap, boost::noncopyable>("World")
            .def("greet", pure_virtual(&World::greet));

    def("test", test);
}
```

Python side:

```
import hello


class HomeWorld(hello.World):
    """ Implements a function defined in C++ as pure virtual """
    def greet(self):
        return "howdy"

home = HomeWorld()
print (hello.test(home))
```

Comment: It's a little hard to follow what you're trying to get at, and I don't think this allows the creation of custom classes with custom members at run-time in a target language.  If we can be on the same page, I'd like to follow something with Lua if you're at all familiar with it.

Comment: @MikeWeir How would you access a runtime-created member of a runtime-created class in C++?

Comment: My `Instance` class would have a type, and a vector of values corresponding to the type's members.

Comment: @MikeWeir It looks like you are describing a map (or a vector or whatever). Is there anything you would like your runtime system to do that a regular `std::map` cannot do? Please show an example.

Comment: This answer requires generated code, and thus does not satisfy the question.

Comment: No worries, I don't understand your question anyway.

Comment: I've made several edits to make it more clear.  You seem to be the closest one, but I think you're over-complicating the solution.  I'm simply seeking how one adds a custom-named class with custom named members/functions to Lua at run-time, while of course having static C++ code that handles it generically somehow (via lookup tables or what have you).

Answer (score 1):

Consider following Lua multimap example.

```lua
Multimap = {};

function Multimap:__index(key)
    if (key == 'keys') then
        local ret = {}
        for k,_ in pairs(self) do
            ret[#ret+1] = k;
        end
        return ret;
    else
        return rawget(getmetatable(self), key)
    end
end

function Multimap.Create()
    local self = {};
    setmetatable(self, Multimap);
    return self;
end

function Multimap:Insert(key, value)
    local list = self[key];
    if (list == nil) then
        list = {};
        self[key] = list;
    end
    table.insert(list, value);
end

function Multimap:Remove(key, value)
    local list = self[key];
    assert(list ~= nil, "key not found");
    for i = 1,#list do
        if (list[i] == value) then
            table.remove(list, i);
            if (#list == 0) then
                self[key] = nil;
            end
            return;
        end
    end
    error("value not found");
end


-- testing

m = Multimap.Create()
m:Insert(1,5)
m:Insert(2,6)
m:Insert(3,7)
m:Insert(1,8)
m:Remove(2,6)
print(pcall(function() 
    m:Remove(2,6)   -- will produce assert exception
end))

print("keys left: ", table.concat(m.keys, ','))
```

You can implement this in C++ in several ways.

1. Use heavy Lua API. The code below is almost exact to Lua.

```cpp
#include <Lua/src/lua.hpp>

int Multimap_Index(lua_State* L) {
    lua_settop(L, 2);       // force 2 arguments

    const char *key_value = "key";
    size_t key_len;
    const char *key = lua_tolstring(L, 2, &key_len);
    if (!strncmp(key, key_value, strlen(key_value))) {
        int i = 0;
        lua_newtable(L);                // stack : self, key, ret = {}
        int ret = lua_gettop(L);
        lua_pushnil(L);                 // stack : self, key, ret, nil
        while (lua_next(L, 1) != 0) {   // stack : self, key, ret, k, v
            lua_pop(L, 1);              // stack : self, key, ret, k
            lua_len(L, ret);            // stack : self, key, ret, k, #ret
            lua_pushvalue(L, -2);       // stack : self, key, ret, k, #ret, k
            lua_rawseti(L, ret, lua_tointeger(L, -2)+1); // ret[#ret+1] = k ; || stack : self, key, ret, k, #ret
            lua_pop(L, 1);              // stack : self, key, ret, k
        }
        // stack : self, key, ret
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        lua_getmetatable(L, 1);     // stack : self, key, metatable(self)
        lua_pushvalue(L, 2);        // stack : self, key, metatable(self), key
        lua_rawget(L, -2);          // stack : self, key, metatable(self), rawget(metatable(self), key)
        return 1;
    }
}

int Multimap_Remove(lua_State* L) {
    lua_settop(L, 3);               // force 3 arguments: self, key, value
    lua_checkstack(L, 12);          // reserve 12 arguments on stack (just in case)
    lua_pushvalue(L, 2);            // stack: self, key, value, key
    lua_gettable(L, 1);             // stack: self, key, value, list = self[key]
    if (lua_isnil(L, -1))
        luaL_error(L, "key not found");
    lua_len(L, -1);                 // stack: self, key, value, list, #list
    int count = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
    lua_pop(L, 1);                  // stack: self, key, value, list
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i) {
        lua_rawgeti(L, -1, i);      // stack: self, key, value, list, v = list[i]
        if (lua_compare(L, 3, 5, LUA_OPEQ)) {   // if (list[i] == value)
            lua_getglobal(L, "table");      // stack : self, key, value, list, v, table
            lua_getfield(L, -1, "remove");  // stack : self, key, value, list, v, table, table.remove
            lua_pushvalue(L, 4);
            lua_pushinteger(L, i);          // stack : self, key, value, list, v, table, table.remove, list, i
            lua_call(L, 2, 0);              // table.remove(list, i); || stack : self, key, value, list, v, table
            lua_pushnil(L);
            if (lua_next(L, 4) == 0) {      // if list is empty table
                lua_pushvalue(L, 2);
                lua_pushnil(L);
                lua_settable(L, 1);         // self[key] = nil
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    luaL_error(L, "value not found");
}

int main() {
    auto L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    lua_newtable(L);
    int Multimap = lua_gettop(L);           // Multimap = {}
    lua_pushvalue(L, Multimap);
    lua_setglobal(L, "Multimap");           // _G.Multimap = Multimap;

    // option 1: create a C function for operation
    // Multimap.__index = &Multimap_Index
    lua_pushcfunction(L, Multimap_Index);
    lua_setfield(L, Multimap, "__index");

    // option 2: compile Lua code and use it
    luaL_loadstring(L,
        "local self = {};\n"
        "setmetatable(self, Multimap);\n"
        "return self;\n"
    );
    lua_setfield(L, Multimap, "Create");    // Multimap.Create = &Multimap_Create

    luaL_loadstring(L,
        "local self, key, value = ...;\n"   // initialize local variables from parameters here
        "local list = self[key];\n"
        "if (list == nil) then\n"
        "   list = {};\n"
        "   self[key] = list;\n"
        "end\n"
        "table.insert(list, value);\n"
    );
    lua_setfield(L, Multimap, "Insert");    // Multimap.Create = &Multimap_Insert

    lua_pushcfunction(L, Multimap_Remove);
    lua_setfield(L, Multimap, "Remove");    // Multimap.Create = &Multimap_Remove

    lua_getfield(L, Multimap, "Create");
    lua_call(L, 0, 1);
    int m = lua_gettop(L);
    lua_getfield(L, m, "Insert");           // stack : m, m.insert
    int Insert = lua_gettop(L);

    // m.Insert(m, 1, 5)
    lua_pushvalue(L, Insert);
    lua_pushvalue(L, m);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 1);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 5);
    lua_call(L, 3, 0);

    // m.Insert(m, 2, 6)
    lua_pushvalue(L, Insert);
    lua_pushvalue(L, m);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 2);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 6);
    lua_call(L, 3, 0);

    // m.Insert(m, 3, 7)
    lua_pushvalue(L, Insert);
    lua_pushvalue(L, m);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 3);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 7);
    lua_call(L, 3, 0);

    // m.Insert(m, 1, 8)
    lua_pushvalue(L, Insert);
    lua_pushvalue(L, m);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 1);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 8);
    lua_call(L, 3, 0);

    // m.Remove(m, 2, 6)
    lua_getfield(L, m, "Remove");
    lua_pushvalue(L, m);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 2);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 6);
    lua_call(L, 3, 0);

    // m.Remove(m, 2, 6)
    lua_getfield(L, m, "Remove");
    lua_pushvalue(L, m);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 2);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 6);
    lua_pcall(L, 3, 0, 0);
    printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));

    lua_getglobal(L, "table");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "concat");
    lua_getfield(L, m, "keys");
    lua_pushstring(L, ",");
    lua_call(L, 2, 1);
    printf("keys left: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));

    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

2. OR you can use Lua userdata that uses std::multimap (I would need another hour to implement this, so ask if you really need that -- that doesn't follow from your question)

Comment: Honestly, I was hoping for something using Lua userdata as I need a more generalized solution allowing custom classes at run-time. I've modified my question to be a bit more specific.

Comment: @MikeWeir you still should think about your limits. `C++` is limited at runtime (comparing with C# for example -- there's no such thing as `dynamic` type in C++ that C# has). Thus you can't dynamically add properties to your C++ classes. Moreover, if you look at Lua, C++ has no similar thing to Lua table, because Lua table can contain different types as a key and value: `t = { [0] = "5", t = {}, ok = true }`

Comment: C++ is unfortunately a requirement I cannot change.  See my question edit to make note of how I've created these classes (which is just a struct defining it) and instances are created.

Comment: Your one and only solution #1 is a custom solution for a specific class and thus would require me to generate code, and thus does not satisfy the question.

Comment: I really don't understand exactly what you want. Have you written already how do you want it to look in c++? I mean, class interface? Providing full solution to you based on c++ templates is way more than a answer to a question and deserves a separate project. Consider reading this, if you don't see enough bottlenecks. http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2015-01/msg00167.html I'm not sure that ppl here can build app architecture for you. One reason - they even don't understand what you're trying to achieve. There's no "Graale" in connecting lua to C++.

Answer (score -1):

*Disclaimer:*  I'm posting this contribution as an answer because I don't have enough reputation points to add a comment.

**Comment:**  Setting aside the problematic of binding with a specific scripting language, it seems that you are facing a fundamental limitation of the `C++` language: it is not "[dynamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language)" (as pointed out by other comments).  That is, the language does not provide any functionality to extend or modify a compiled program.

Maybe all hope is not lost, though.  Searching the web for "c++ dynamic loading" reveals that some systems (such and Linux and Windows) do seem to implement a [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) mechanism.

Here are the links to two (old) articles that talk about the subject.

1. *[Dynamic Class Loading for C++ on Linux](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3687?page=0,0)* in the Linux Journal.
2. *[Dynamically Loaded C++ Objects](http://www.drdobbs.com/dynamically-loaded-c-objects/184401900)* in Dr.Dobb's.

They seem interesting at first glance.  I'm not sure they are still relevant, though.

This is but a shot in the dark.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not looking for a solution that would restrict me to a specific platform or one that would require the use of dynamic library loading.  I'll update my question accordingly.